# Which of the following CSS tidbits will my broswer parse faster into the document object?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to optimize my `CSS`. Which of the following equivalent pieces of code will my browser process faster?

```
margin: 0px;
margin-right: 10px;
```

or

```
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
```

Comment: tip: no need to specify units if the value is 0! `margin: 0 10px 0 0;`

Comment: The difference should be negligible. CSS is parsed once and generally there is little to work with in terms of how you split your CSS statements as far as performance is concerned. I'd focus on _what_ your CSS is doing, rather than how you arrange your statements.

Comment: Satya, *faster* in this case is relative... The speed's difference (if any) would be irrelevant..

Comment: check this: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just:

```
margin-right: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any savings made by choosing one form over the other are utterly negligible in comparison with optimizations that can be made from image processing, cutting down on HTTP calls, removing unnecessary javascript, and other such measures.

The advantage of specifying `margin: 0 10px 0 0` over `margin-right: 10px` is that you're much less likely to suffer from other margin styling declarations acting on whatever you've applied the 10px right margin to. Of course, in some situations, you may want to inherit margin styling from parent elements or classes, so it may be preferable not to specify values.

Optimising css should be done within a broader sweep of web page optimizations; I've yet to have a web page load slowly due to its css file, whereas there are plenty of websites I've abandoned while waiting for some huge image to load, some fancy (but ultimately useless) JS effect, or the mere sight of a flash plugin. Look at [Google Page View](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) or [Yahoo's YSlow](https://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), and concentrate your efforts on areas that will yield noticeable benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The render speed in this case would be irrelevant. Let's consider at least two points of view:

**1 - Less written stuff:**

Defining only shorthanded technically there are less bytes on the file.

```
margin: 0;
margin-right: 10px;
```

vs

```
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
```

**2 - Less rules to render:**

On the other hand, shorthanded you'd be making the browser render unecessary rules (top, right, bottom, left), when you could use just one:

```
margin: 0 10px 0 0; /* Defines top right bottom left; */
```

vs

```
margin-right: 10px; /* Only right */
```

**CONCLUSION:**

Your decision on use or not an shorthanded property should not be based on speed, but on quality. Shorthands have a specific purpose:

[**From MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)

> **Definition**
>   Shorthand properties are CSS properties that let you set the values of several other CSS properties simultaneously. Using a shorthand property, a Web developer can write more concise and often more readable style sheets, saving time and energy.

Comment: Re: fewer rules to render: that is not quite correct, as the browser will use its built-in stylesheet to determine the margins if they are not set in the page css.

Comment: @ialarmedalien - Actually the browser's *user agent* always render it's default rules, and then override them with defined ones...

Comment: We're quibbling over semantics.